# Template for extracting POST values in Django

Tags: python, django, post

I'm new to Django. I have client application, that sends POST request to the server to create a new Conference object on the server. Serverside code looks like this:

```
new_conf.date = request.POST['date']
new_conf.name = request.POST['name']
new_conf.languages = request.POST['languages']
new_conf.is_open = request.POST['is_open']
new_conf.place = request.POST['place']
new_conf.recognition_on = request.POST['recognition_on']
```

Is there a way to write it shorter? Is it possible to write some general template to use in similar situations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make a [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/) form your model, and have it "unpack" the request.POST data into a model instance

```
# Create a form instance from POST data.
>>> conf_form = ConferenceForm(request.POST)

# Save a new Conference object from the form's data.
>>> new_conf = conf_form.save()
```

ref. https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

Or, for a more Python-generic solution, you can make a list of keys you want and use [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr) or set the keys in your [dict](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), like below

```
for key in ['date', 'name', 'languages', ...]:
    setattr(new_conf, key, request.POST[key])

    # Or if new_conf is a dict-like obj
    new_conf[key] = request.POST[key]
```